# How to turn on 3G, Wifi or GPS in Android?

Tags: android, gps, location, android-wifi, 3g

I am writing an application related to location. Nevertheless, I need to turn on the Wifi/3G and GPS in case it is off before other functions can process. I have searched but I did not see any way to auto turn on 3g/wifi and GPS. How to start this functionality by coding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Code is use to start Wifi programatically.

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifi.setWifiEnabled(enabled);
```

You need to add following permission in to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. Do I have to add some library or add something in AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 0):

If you are finding any difficulties in turning on 3G on your Android device then follow the below steps.

- Tap the Menu icon.
- Scroll towards right and select settings from the list.
- Select Wireless Controls or Wireless & networks (as per OS versions).
- Scroll down to select Mobile Networks.
- You will get a list on the screen from which you have to select Network Mode.
- A dialogue box will get populated in front of you with different options like WCDMA    only, GSM only and GSM/WCDMA preferred. You have to select GSM/WCDMA preferred option.
- As soon as you will select this option, 3G is enabled on your phone.

Now if you are in 3G-enabled area and your device is 3G compatible, you are good to enjoy high speed internet services on your mobile phone.

Comment: the question is about how to programmatically activate those